# How to configure VNC server to give the standard Ubuntu desktop

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver

There are several VNC server tutorials that I could find, but they all show only how to provide a bare-bones xfce desktop.

What is the configuration to provide the identical, normal Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Are you willing to install a desktop on the remote system?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'd like to connect from a Mac or Chromebook.